# std::unordered_set<std::filesystem::path>: compile error on clang and g++ below v.12. Bug or user error?

Tags: c++, g++, c++17, clang, std-filesystem

I added the following function template to my project, and a user complained that it wouldn't compile on their system anymore:

```cpp
template<typename T>
std::size_t removeDuplicates(std::vector<T>& vec)
{
    std::unordered_set<T> seen;

    auto newEnd = std::remove_if(
        vec.begin(), vec.end(), [&seen](const T& value)
        {
            if (seen.find(value) != std::end(seen))
                return true;

            seen.insert(value);
            return false;
        }
    );

    vec.erase(newEnd, vec.end());

    return vec.size();
}
```

The error message with `g++ 9.4` was approximately

```
error: use of deleted function
'std::unordered_set<_Value, _Hash, _Pred, _Alloc>::unordered_set() 
[with
_Value = std::filesystem::__cxx11::path; 
_Hash = std::hash<std::filesystem::__cxx11::path>; 
_Pred = std::equal_to<std::filesystem::__cxx11::path>; 
_Alloc = std::allocator<std::filesystem::__cxx11::path>]'
   12 |  std::unordered_set<T> seen;
```

So the error arose when instantiating the above function template with `T = std::filesystem::path`.
I investigated a little and found that there was no issue when instantiating it with other types, e.g. fundamental types or `std::string`, but only with `std::filesystem::path`.

Using [Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/KPzbWE69M), I looked at how different compiler versions treat the code and found that *only* `g++ v.12` can compile the instantiation with `std::filesystem::path`. Any `g++` version below 12 fails with the above error. `clang` produces a similar error (`call to implicitly deleted default constructor`), even on the newest version (14). I didn't test other compilers.

The workaround I used was substituting `std::unordered_set` with `std::set`. Then it works on `g++ v.8` and `clang v.7` and above.

So I guess the error is a missing hashing function for `std::filesystem::path`? Or is it an error on my part?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `std::hash` specialization for `std::filesystem::path` has only recently been added as resolution of [LWG issue 3657](https://wg21.link/lwg3657) into the standard draft. It hasn't been there in the published C++17 and C++20 standards.

There has always been however a function [`std::filesystem::hash_value`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/path/hash_value) from which you can easily create a function object to pass as hash function to `std::unordered_set`:

```
struct PathHash {
    auto operator()(const std::filesystem::path& p) const noexcept {
        return std::filesystem::hash_value(p);
    }
};

//...

std::unordered_set<std::filesystem::path, PathHash> seen;
```

---

If you are providing that template without any guarantees that it works on types other than those that have a `std::hash` specialization defined, then I think there is no problem on your part.

However, if you require the type to be hashable, it would be a good idea to let the user override the hash function used the same way `std::unordered_set` does. The same also applies to the equality functor used.

Answer (score 0):

To add to the answer that std::hashstd::filesystem::path was added in C++17, it is actually implemented in the following versions of standard libraries:

| C++ Standard Library | Version |
| --- | --- |
| GCC libstdc++ | v11.4 |
| Clang libc++ | 17 |
| MSVC STL | 19.32 |

Source: [CPP Reference C++17 Compiler Support](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support/17)